# How to debug a live server?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm taking a course which as a problem set requires building upon a teacher-provided C server framework. I've completed the server insomuch as it compiles without error, but as expected I'm getting weird bugs and the inevitable segmentation fault. I usually use GDB to chase this sort of thing down but I'm not sure how to do that when the only way I can get an error is to have the server running and submit an HTTP GET request.

What methods are there for debugging a program like this?

Comment: I usually use valgrind while compiling with `gcc -g3` to hunt segfaults.

Comment: I tried just running valgrind on the program and actually managed to crash valgrind itself. I didn't even know that was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that launching the program with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) will cause the server to actually "go live" and allow memory leak debugging. My segmentation fault was coming from:

```
char* extensionlowered = "/0";
strcpy(extensionlowered, extension);
extensionlowered[strlen(extensionlowered) + 1] = '\0';
```

`extensionlowered` only had access to the initial `\0` byte. When I tried to copy more than that into it, I caused a segmentation fault. The fixed code is

```
char* extensionlowered = malloc(sizeof(extension) + 1);
strcpy(extensionlowered, extension);
extensionlowered[strlen(extensionlowered) + 1] = '\0';
```

EDIT:

Furthermore, if GDB is used to launch the server and a breakpoint set, the server will "go live" but won't respond to requests until the breakpoint allows it. So I launched gdb `gdb server` , then `break (line)`, then `run arg 1 arg 2 arg 3`. The server came online when I `step`ped through the program and got to the main loop, and responded to the request at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps logging debug/error info to a file in the server (each message with a  timestamp)? You can always check the contents of the file:

```
2015-10-15-16:42:00 - Log1
2015-10-15-16:42:05 - Log2
2015-10-15-16:42:11 - Error1
...
```